# Facebook sdk not using already installed app for login iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to use Facebook app, if it is installed in device for login through Facebook in my iOS app. Right now its redirecting to safari browser, whether app is installed or not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<id>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];    

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:nsurl]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:nsurl];
}
else {
    //Open the url as usual
}

Answer (score 0):

Policy of Facebook login is been changed. Nothing wrong with iOS 10.

Refer - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

You have to give behavior to native like below.

```
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
```

Make sure 1 thing, if user doesn't have Facebook app then.

So better to use. which will open Facebook login page on your login view controller within app only.

```
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

**Sample code**

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;

    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error)  {
             NSLog(@"Process error");

         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         }
         else {
             if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email, name"}]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error) {
                          NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

                      }
                  }];
             }
         }
     }];
```

Just click on FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative, it will lead you to FacebookLoginManager.h

Read it properly and understand.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSDKLoginBehavior)
{
  /*!
   @abstract This is the default behavior, and indicates logging in through the native
   Facebook app may be used. The SDK may still use Safari instead.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative = 0,
  /*!
   @abstract Attempts log in through the Safari or SFSafariViewController, if available.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser,
  /*!
   @abstract Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through
   the device Settings.
   @note If the account is not available to the app (either not configured by user or
   as determined by the SDK) this behavior falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount,
  /*!
   @abstract Attempts log in through a modal \c UIWebView pop up

   @note This behavior is only available to certain types of apps. Please check the Facebook
   Platform Policy to verify your app meets the restrictions.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb,
};
```

Comment: Hello @Hasya , Thanks for reply but i have tried your code , but not able to get login through native iOS app if installed. i want to do as if app is installed then it will open facebook app else redirect to browser